# How to read-from-string, but keep strings inside as it is?

Tags: message, read

With a elisp piece of code:

```
(message "%s" (read-from-string "(setq a \"a string here\" )"))
```

I got result:

```
((setq a a string here) . 25)
```

But I want result is:

```
((setq a "a string here") . xxx )
```

I can't find in document info to do this

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Nothing in your question shows an attempt to create a dotted list with `25` or `xxx` as cdr. And none of the code you said you tried does that. Please clarify the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%s means print a string argument.  Actually, prints any object, with ‘princ’.
%S means print any object as an s-expression (using ‘prin1’).
```

Hence:

```
(message "%S" (read-from-string "(setq a \"a string here\" )"))
=> "((setq a \"a string here\") . 25)"
```

I.e. The `read-from-string` return value was fine already; it was just the way you were printing it; `princ` vs `prin1`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! The command works fine.